# How can i speed up the execution of pandas code?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have an address_objects DataFrame containing 1,917,866 entries with these columns and datatypes
`{'Id': dtype('int64'), 'ObjectId': dtype('int64'), 'ObjectGuid': dtype('O'), 'ChangeId': dtype('int64'), 'Name': dtype ('O'), 'TypeName': dtype('O'), 'Level': dtype('int64'), 'OperationType': dtype('int64'), 'PrevId': dtype('int64'), 'NextId': dtype('int64'), 'UpdateDate': dtype('O'), 'StartDate': dtype('O'), 'EndDate': dtype('O'), 'IsActual': dtype( 'int64'), 'IsActive': dtype('int64'), 'changed_name': dtype('O')}`

And I have a dictionary called bests_paths like `{'78545 78727 74726 86145 84657': 4, '78545 78727 81007 101612304': 4, '78545 78727 81007 101612305': 4, '78 545 78727 81007 101612306': 3, '78545 78727 81007 101612307': 3` ... etc. where the key is a string in which the ObjectId from the above DataFrame is separated by spaces. The set of such ObjectIds in the key is a certain mailing address
My task is to get all the addresses from the address_objects DataFrame by the key from the dictionary, perform some simple calculations and write the received addresses with the calculations into a new DataFrame.

My problem is the speed of getting a new DataFrame with addresses. For example, if the bests_paths dictionary contains 815 key-value pairs, then it takes about 15 seconds to create it, which is not acceptable for me. For example, it takes about 40 seconds to sort through a dictionary containing about 2000 entries.

I am new to Pandas and now my code looks like this

```
for path, power in bests_paths.items():
            path = list(map(int, path.split()))
            address = address_objects.loc[address_objects['ObjectId'].isin(path)]
            sort = address.sort_values(by=['IsActual', 'IsActive'], ascending=[False, False])
            idx = sort['ObjectId'].drop_duplicates(keep='first').index 
            address = sort.loc[idx, :] 
            
            missing_components = a + b #some simple calculations

            address['Path'] = '.'.join(map(str, path))
            address['PowerPath'] = power - missing_components
            address['MissingComponent'] = missing_components
            addresses_administrative_hierarchy = pd.concat([addresses_administrative_hierarchy, address])
```

What in this code slows down its execution so much? Could you give me advice on how to optimize it in order to increase the speed of its execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is slow because you're making the following rookie mistakes:

- Using `loc` and `isin` for each iteration. This will scan through the DataFrame multiple times.
- Sorting the DataFrame in each iteration.
- Dropping duplicates in each iteration.
- Concatenating DataFrames using `pd.concat` in a loop.
- Usage of Python's built-in `map` and `list` inside a loop with Pandas operations.

Instead start by:

1. Pre-sorting and indexing your Dataframe
2. Use a `list` to store intermediate DataFrames
3. Use `loc` for faster lookups
4. Vectorise your operations

The code below could be faster by an order of magnitude or two.

```
import pandas as pd


"""
Sample data and dictionary (you will use your actual DataFrame and dictionary)
address_objects = your actual DataFrame
bests_paths = your actual dictionary
"""

# Step 1: Pre-sort and index DataFrame
# This speeds up the lookup operation dramatically as Pandas can now use the optimized index for data selection.
# It also sorts the DataFrame by 'IsActual' and 'IsActive' in descending order,
# which eliminates the need to sort it inside the loop.

address_objects = address_objects.sort_values(
    ['ObjectId', 'IsActual', 'IsActive'], ascending=[True, False, False])
address_objects = address_objects.drop_duplicates(
    subset='ObjectId', keep='first')
address_objects.set_index('ObjectId', inplace=True)

# Step 2: Use a list to store intermediate DataFrames
# Storing the DataFrames in a list and using `pd.concat` just once is much faster
# than concatenating DataFrames within the loop.
addresses_list = []

for path, power in bests_paths.items():
    # Convert the string path to a list of integers.
    # Since we need to do this anyway, no specific optimization here.
    path = list(map(int, path.split()))

    # Step 3: Use loc ( and isin() ) for faster lookups
    # The loc function benefits from the DataFrame index and provides a faster lookup.
    address = address_objects.loc[path]

    # Your simple calculations (no changes here since this is specific to your logic)
    missing_components = a + b

    # Step 4: Vectorised operations
    # These are vectorised, which is faster than looping through each row to set these values.
    address['Path'] = '.'.join(map(str, path))
    address['PowerPath'] = power - missing_components
    address['MissingComponent'] = missing_components

    # Add this DataFrame to the list
    addresses_list.append(address)

# Step 5: Concatenate once
# Concatenating just once at the end is more efficient than doing it in each iteration.
addresses_administrative_hierarchy = pd.concat(addresses_list)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Now the same cycle with 815 entries is completed in 6 seconds. But path doesn't always have ObjectId which are indexes in address_objects. In this connection, I get an error like KeyError: '[79116] not in index'
So I have to check if the index exists before calling loc.1. before the loop address_objects_set = set(address_objects.index.tolist())
2. if not len(path) -len(set(path).intersection(address_objects_set)): address = address_objects.loc[path] I think that such a check can take a lot of time. Is there no way to quickly check if an index exists in a df?

Comment: Or this option
address_objects[address_objects.index.isin(path)]

Comment: or address = address_objects.loc[list(address_objects_set.intersection(set(path)))]

Comment: Yes the isin() method would be the best way to do this. Something like...     address = address_objects.loc[address_objects.index.isin(path)]
    if not address.empty: